# WPF WebBrowser shows two horizontal lines

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

In one of the applications I work on, I found a very strange issue with a WPF `WebBrowser` control that we use to display a local html file.

The web browser control scrollbar initially displays two horizontal lines as shown in this picture: 
[image: two horizontal lines on the scrollbar]

As soon as the user scrolls, the lines disappear.

Has anyone else experienced this? I think it is something to do with an `Height` not set or set incorrectly somewhere...

Unfortunately the code is too messy and convoluted to share as is. I will try to replicate in isolation and post the code in due course.

One of my colleagues has already tried the following but no success so far:

- Changing verticalAlignment property to center/stretch/top/down of grid (which is inside scrollviewer)
- Changing margin property of scrollviewer so that scrollbar should appear little down by default as the lines were disappearing after moving the scroll bar. But in this case, whole textbox was moving because the grid is placed inside the scrollviewer.
- Applying style to scrollbar of scrollviewer to move only scrollbar not full text:

  `<ScrollViewer.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
     <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">

         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,50,0,0"/> //tried different values
       </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ScrollViewer.Resources>`
- Changing different setter properties(`BoarderBrush`, `Thickness`, `VerticalAlignment` etc.) in CommonStyles.xaml file
- Add line of code `LoadCompleted` event `currentlyDisplayedHtmlDocument.body.style.overflow = "auto";`

Comment: I wonder if this could be a bug in the WebBrowser control itself.

Comment: If it is a bug with the control itself then someone else must have come across it before...

Comment: Try hosting this control in an empty solution. See if that behavior is still present if not, then add stuff to it to see what causes it.

Comment: I've just tried loading google in WebBrowser control. Unfortunately, there is no second scrollbar. There is definitely something wrong in the code you are not showing.